# tf.shape(image) returns None in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I was using Tensorflow 2.0 to build a super resolution model. During pre-processing, I wanted to crop both the low and high resolution images by a given patch size. In order to do so, I wanted to get the height and width of the low and high resolution images. But tf.shape(image) is returning None. 
Is there a better approach?

Currently I am just resizing every image to some size before using tf.shape, but since not all images have equal size, it is affecting the quality of the imaged. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Edited part:
Here is some parts of the code

low_r = tf.io.decode_jpeg(lr_filename, channels=3)

low_r = tf.cast(low_r, dtype=tf.float32)

print(low_r.shape)

The print statement prints (None, None, 3)
What I wanted was to get the height and weight, like (240,360,3)

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide code.

Comment: please give a look at it. I provided my code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm unable to repeat your issue, but this should give you a way to test out your Tensorflow 2.0 install and compare with the results you're currently getting.

Create a tensor and check it's shape:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
tf.shape(t)  # [2, 2, 3]

Out[1]: <tf.Tensor: id=1, shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 2, 3])>
```

Next, checking what the function return when called:

```
tf_shape_var = tf.shape(t)
print(tf_shape_var)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([2 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

Finally, calling it on an int and string to get back a valid return:

```
tf.shape(1)
Out[10]: <tf.Tensor: id=12, shape=(0,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([], dtype=int32)>

tf.shape('asd')
Out[11]: <tf.Tensor: id=15, shape=(0,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([], dtype=int32)>
```

And the print statements:

```
print(tf.shape(1))
print(tf.shape('asd'))
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([], shape=(0,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([], shape=(0,), dtype=int32)
```

Link for `tf.shape()` https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/shape

Comment: I think OP is decoding a image which is computed lazily hence causing None, None.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is also your case, but in my `TensorFlow` (`v2.4.0rc2`), `my_tensor.shape()` also returns `TensorShape([None, None, None, None])`. It is connected to the fact that the `TensorShape` tensor is generated during the build and not during the execution.

Using `tf.shape()` (mentioned in your question, but not used in your code snippet actually) solves it for me.

```
> my_tensor.shape()
TensorShape([None, None, None, None])
> tf.shape(my_tensor)
[10 512 512 8]
```